# Confusion on rebuttal to Cantor's diagonalization method in "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In Abbott's book (2nd edition) there is an exercise (1.6.3) given in chapter 1 where we are asked to address two rebuttals to cantor's proof that $(0,1)\subseteq R$ is uncountable. I don't understand the solution to the second rebuttal.

**background information:** the proof uses a contradiction. It assumes (for sake of contradiction) that there is some bijective function $f:N\rightarrow (0,1)$ such that $f(n)=0.a_{n1}a_{n2}a_{n3}...$ It then says that if we let $x=0.b_1b_2b_3...$ where $b_n=\begin{cases}
2\ if\ a_{nn}\neq 2\\
3\ if\ a_{nn}=2
\end{cases}$ then x will not be in the range of f, and therefore a contradiction is reached and $(0,1)$ is uncountable (since we can't make a bijective function between the natural numbers and the interval).

I understand this proof, but a follow up exercise is given immediately after the proof in which we are tasked with addressing two rebuttals.

**rebuttal:** "Some numbers have two different decimal representations. Specifically,
any decimal expansion that terminates can also be written with repeating
9’s. For instance, 1/2 can be written as .5 or as .4999 . . . . Doesn’t this
cause some problems?"

**The solution to this rebuttal I obtained from the solutions manual:** " By using the digits 2 and 3 in our definition of $b_n$ we eliminate the
possibility that the point $x = .b_1b_2b_3 . . .$ has some other possible decimal representation (and thus it cannot exist somewhere in the range of f in a different
form.)

I don't understand the significance of choosing 2 and 3 as our digits to switch around. How does this choice address the rebuttal stated above?

Comment: By using only digits $2$ and $3$ they are, in particular, never using $9$ or $0$, which are the ones that create ambiguous representations. Namely the representations $0.a_1a_2...a_n000...$ with $a_n\neq0$ and $0.a_1a_2...(a_n-1)999...$ of the rational number $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\cdot 10^{k}$.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in the decimal expression of any real number subject to the requirement that only those two digits appear.

Comment: Ok, so after reading both comments by lulu and conditionalMethod I want to make sure I understand. Are the only "problem" digits 0 and 9? I.e. could we have used any two digits besides 0 and 9 and the proof would hold?

Comment: Yes, only representations of the form above are ambiguous. They could have used any other way of avoiding getting a representation of those forms.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a very good chance this question has been asked here before - there have been a lot of Cantor questions on this site over the years - but I can't find an exact duplicate at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the rebuttal above didn't go into detail about *how* multiple decimal expansions could create problems; part of the exercise is to identify exactly what issue could arise.

There are two key points:

- The "antidiagonal" real $x$ needs to be **well-defined**. Specifically, if $f(n)$ has two different decimal representations $0.a_1a_2...$ and $0.a_1'a_2'...$, it needs to be the case that it doesn't matter which we use when we compute $x$.
- The "antidiagonal" real $x$ needs to be **not in the range of $f$**. We claimed that $x\not=f(17)$ (say) based on a difference in their decimal expansions. But maybe we were looking at the wrong decimal expansions - maybe *one* of $x$'s decimal expansions is different from *one* of $f(17)$'s decimal expansions, but $x=f(17)$ nonetheless (e.g. we thought of $f(17)$ as $0.10000...$ and we thought of $x$ as $0.0999999$...).

The point is that by focusing on $2$ and $3$ - and in particular, by staying away from $0$ and $9$ - we've avoided both these problems.